# Error when using export/import SQL file from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

There's something I've done a hundred times: exporting a mysql database from one server and importing it into another. The export function provides an `.sql` file which then gets imported to the new server. However, my servers recently updated their phpMyAdmin version (currently 4.6.0) and now whenever I try to do that I get an error when trying to import. I think that has something to do with the escaping as one of the lines now looks like that in the exported file:

```
(5, 'that\\\'s not even', '2014-05-25 22:35:51', 0)
```

That is a part of INSERT statement for one of the tables and the triple `\\\` is what bothers me. I've tried to look around the configuration and find something related to the escaping but alas no luck. No sure if that's the issue really but any tip on what might be wrong and how to fix it is more than welcome.

EDIT:

In face, that line seems to have nothing in common with the error. The error that gets displayed on import is the following:
Static analysis:

> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 2615077)

After that a very long query follows and I also don't know if that's relevant or not but it ends with this following line which is far from being last:

```
(33, 'active_plugins', 'a:2:{i:0;s:37:"admin-in-english/admin-in-english.php";i:1;s:29:"filedownload/filedownload.php";}', 'yes'),
```

That last one in particular is from a bunch of WordPress tables in the database if that matters.

EDIT2:
And here's something even more interesting. I keep backups of old database dumps so I tried to import a dump from a couple of months back that definitely imported successfully back then. Right now, same file, but error once I try to do the import...

Comment: why do you think that you have something wrong? to me it seems that you just had not very best value in original db `that\'s` and that is why you have it exported. What error do you have in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your string: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e17b/1  Provide more details about any error you have

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've provided a bit more information above about the error that gets displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of headbanging it turns out that the problem was limitations imposed by PHP for files larger than 6MB. After 6MB of query it would just cut it right there and logically throw and error afterwards.

The solution is either to change them or in my case, as I don't have direct access to the configuration files: SSH import worked successfully.